# XML Android Banner

Tags: android, xml

Ok so I have this code but i get an error in LogCat when i launch the app:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/menubackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/gameicon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/game_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_title_size"
            android:textColor="@color/golden_yellow"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/gameicon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If I remove the 2x image views and text view it launches up so the problem might be there..
And I also get a warning on RelativeLayout "The RelativeLayout or its parent LinearLayout is useless"

Comment: Read the error. If you can't understand it, google it. If you still can't solve it, post the error log here. There's no need to brute force search for the cause (sometimes there is, but don't start there :p)

Comment: Which error? where's the LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mast set :`android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for views. 
For example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_file" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting should be a warning not an error.  It is as it states.  You can remove the relative layout or remove the linear layout.  If you remove the linear layout set the background and other information in the relative layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your XML code with this:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** Don`t ever forget to add the`Height`and the`Weight` to your element